# Figuring out what startpar.c (sysvinit) is doing

Tags: c, linux, debian, sysv

OK here's a long one, brace yourself! :)

Recently I tried launching a watchdog script written in bash, during boot. So I added a line to **rc.local** containing the following:

```
su someuser -c "/home/someuser/watchdog.sh &"
```

the watchdog.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
until /home/someuser/eventMonitoring.py
do
    sleep 1
done
```

All is fine, all is good, the script gets started and all. However a new process appears in the processes list, and stays there forever:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      3048     1  0  1024   620   1 20:04 ?        00:00:00 startpar -f -- rc.local
```

Now, my script (watchdog.sh) got launched and was successfully detached because its PPID is also 1. I was then on a mission to find out what that process is. Startpar is part of **sysvinit** boot system (http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit). I'm currently on a Debian Wheezy 7.4.0 which uses that system. Now **`man startpar`** says:

```
startpar is used to run multiple run-level scripts in parallel.
```

By a method of trial and error I basically figured out how to properly launch my script during boot and not leave **startpar** hanging. All file descriptors of a process need to be redirected to either a file or **/dev/null** or closed all together. Which when you think about is a rational thing to do. I finally did it like this:

```
su someuser -c "some_script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

That resolved the issue. But still left me wondering why that is. Why **startpar** behaves like it does. Is it a bug or is it a feature.

So I dived a bit into the code(http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/startpar/trunk/startpar.c?root=sysvinit&view=markup) and started going from the end to the beginning:

First I located where that **startpar -f -- rc.local** call is made:
**line 741:**

```
execlp(myname, myname, "-f", "--", p->name, NULL);
```

Ok so this will actually start a new **startpar** process which will replace the current running instance. It's basically a recursive call on itself. Lets look what that **-f** parameter does:

**line 866:**

```
case 'f':
      forw = 1;
      break;
```

OK, let's see what setting **forw** variable to **1** does...
**line 900:**

```
if (forw)
    do_forward();
```

And finally let's see what's up with that function:

**line 615:**

```
void do_forward(void)
{
  char buf[4096], *b;
  ssize_t r, rr;
  setsid();
  while ((r = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf))))
    {
      if (r < 0)
    {
      if (errno == EINTR)
        continue;
#if defined(DEBUG) && (DEBUG > 0)
      perror("\n\rstartpar: forward read");
#endif
      break;
    }
      b = buf;
      while (r > 0)
    {
      rr = write(1, b, r);
      if (rr < 0)
        {
          if (errno == EINTR)
        continue;
          perror("\n\rstartpar: forward write");
          rr = r;
        }
      r -= rr;
      b += rr;
    }
    }
  _exit(0);
}
```

As far as I understand this. This will redirect all that is coming from file descriptor 0, to file descriptor 1. Now let's see what is really linked to those file descriptors:

```
root@server:~# ls -al /proc/3048/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 root root  0 Apr  2 21:13 .
dr-xr-xr-x 8 root root  0 Apr  2 21:13 ..
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  2 21:13 0 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  2 21:13 1 -> /dev/console
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Apr  2 21:13 2 -> /dev/console
```

Hmm interesting... So ptmx is according to man:

```
The file /dev/ptmx is a character file with major number 5 
and minor number 2, usually of mode 0666 and owner.group of root.root. 
It is used to create a pseudoterminal master and slave pair.
```

and console:

```
The current console is also addressed by
/dev/console or /dev/tty0, the character device with major number 4
and minor number 0.
```

And at that point I came here to stackoverflow. Now, can someone tell me what is going on here? Did I get this right, that startpar is left in a stage of constantly redirecting whatever comes to **ptmx** to the **console**? Why is it doing that? Why **ptmx**? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

This is definitely NOT a bug with **`startpar`**, which is doing exactly what it [promises to in the first place](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/startpar.8.html).

> The output of each script is buffered and written when the script exits,  so  output lines of different scripts won't mix. You can modify this behaviour by setting a timeout.

---

### Code details

Within the `run()` function in [**`startpar.c`**](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/startpar/trunk/startpar.c?root=sysvinit&view=markup),

1. Line 422: Obtain a handle to the master pseudoterminal (`/dev/ptmx` in this case)

   `p->fd = getpt();`
2. Line 429: Obtain the path of the corresponding slave pseudoterminal

   `else if ((m = ptsname(p->fd)) == 0 || grantpt(p->fd) || unlockpt(p->fd))`
3. Line 438: Fork a child process

   `if ((p->pid = fork()) == (pid_t)-1)`
4. Line 475: Invalidate default **`stdout`**

   `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(1));`
5. Line 476: Obtain a handle to slave pseudoterminal. Now, this is **`1`**, i.e. the `stdout` of child now redirects to the slave pseudoterminal (and is received by the master pseudoterminal node).

   `if (open(m, O_RDWR) != 1)`
6. Line 481: Also capture **`stderr`** by duplicating it with the salve pseudoterminal fd.

   `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(dup2(1, 2));`
7. Line 561: After some book-keeping stuff, launch the executable of interest(as the child process)

   `execlp(p->name, p->arg0, (char *)0);`
8. The parent process can then later on capture all the output/error logs of this newly launched process by reading the buffered master pseudoterminal and log it to the actual stdout (i.e. `/dev/console` in this case).

---

### How to prevent a dangling `startpar -f ...` process on your system?

#### Method 1: Define the executable to be launched as interactive.

Explicitly marking a executable interactive tells `startpar` to skip the psedoterminal master/slave trickery to buffer the terminal I/O as any output of the launched interactive executable needs to be displayed on screen immediately and not buffered.

This modifies the flow of execution in several places. Mainly at **Line 1171**, where `startpar` does NOT call the `run()` function for an interactive executable.

This has been tested and described [**here**](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=537182#20).

#### Method 2: Discard `stdout` and `stderr` of the executable to be launched.

Using the construct `">/dev/null 2>&1 &"` discard `stdout`/`stderr` of the executable to be launched. If they are both explicitly set to NULL i.e. startpar does NOT buffer them indefinitely as it usually does otherwise.

#### Method 3: Set an explicit timeout for `startpar`

Either configure **`timo`** in `startpar.c`

> The timeout set with the **`-t`** option is used as buffer  timeout. If the output buffer of a script is not empty and the last output was timeout seconds ago, startpar will flush the buffer.

or **`gtimo`** in `startpar.c`

> The **`-T`** option timeout works more globally. If no output is printed for more than global_timeout seconds, startpar will flush the buffer of the script with the oldest output. Afterwards it will only print output of this script until it is finished.

Comment: You said it best yourself: "Its a pity all this is not well documented and it took more than a hour to dig through the source and understand properly."

Comment: I agree with that too! Thanks for the analysis TheCodeArtist, great job!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, and I can see how your investigation got derailed.

The file descriptor 0 refers to **stdin** (standard input). That's just its number in a table somewhere in the Linux kernel. The reason your clever investigation traced that to `/dev/ptmx` is because that is a [pseudo-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) used by the Linux kernel to handle keyboard input.

Likewise, the file descriptor 1 refers to **stdout**. For similar reasons, you can probably see now why that is hooked into your console.

So, yes: this redirects from file descriptor 0 to file descriptor 1, which is to say, from `stdin` to `stdout`. While at first this seemed pretty innocuous to me, apparently there [have been problems with it](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=682654) before, and others ([e.g.](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=75669)) have worked around it just like you did (by redirecting `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to `/dev/null`). AFAICT, that bug report is closed/solved, but as you appear to be on the latest version of Debian I'm not sure why you don't have the fix. I'm a little out of my depth here because I personally use Arch Linux, which doesn't even use sysvinit any more!

**Edit**: Here's another [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=537182) from 2009 involving `rsyslog` being started by `startpar -f` and causing an extra process to hang around with (surprise!) open file descriptors. The solution was the same (close them all).

Comment: The linked bug report mentions nothing about "closing-off" the standard fds to fix the issue! (or am i missing something here?)

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. I linked the bug report because there appears to be a software fix for it. The "most people" was just a `[citation needed]` because I saw the same approach mentioned as a successful workaround on a couple of forums while searching before I found the actual bug. Again, I'm looking at this at a distance because Arch Linux [hasn't supported initscripts](https://www.archlinux.org/news/end-of-initscripts-support/) since 2012.

Comment: I didn't mean to object to the wording. The linked bug-report doesn't seem to mention anything about redirecting the stdin/stdout/stderr fixing the issue. Hence i am still NOT convinced by the argument put forward in this answer. No offense. Just wondering. I too am still trying to understand the recursive flow of code of [startpar](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/startpar/trunk/startpar.c?root=sysvinit&view=markup).

Comment: None taken. I don't fully understand it myself, but given other people seemed to have the same problem (and workaround) a few months ago, and there is a closed bug report, I guess this really might be the same thing. It may be that this is just a partial answer which doesn't fully solve OP's mystery. Edited my answer to add an example on the Debian forums of this workaround being used for a similar issue.

Comment: Guys, first let me say thanks for looking into this! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist(part-1): That the redirection happens is pretty much clear. However not the purpose of it. After all, on my first try when I started my script with only the ampersand(start in background) at the end, that should have closed the stdin for that started process. So I see no reason for startpar, who started it, to (for whatever reason) continue receiving stuff on ptmx.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist(part-2): It's certainly not innocuous, as you also concluded at the end. This all started from my question on Serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/585945/providing-normal-usersnon-root-with-initialization-and-shutdown-auto-run-capab So for example if you have many processes launched like this, this could become an issue. Regarding the linked problems, I found and looked into the first two already before I posted this. The first one does not seem to be related(My boot process completes to the end and I can login successfully).

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist(part-3): The second one does seem related, however it's two years old, and not much discussion there. They have also not figured out why. The third link you provided(in your latest edit), although almost five years old, seems to be right to the point. But interestingly enough the discussion there derailed from pointing to a bug in startpar to declaring that it is a bug in syslogd. That the syslogd should have closed the fds! OK, so likewise I should maybe accept that it is also a bug in my code. But I still ask why?

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist(part-4): Why doesn't startpar redirect the fds itself, what's the purpose of starting a process and then staying in that do_forward loop. There must be some logic behind it. That's basically what I'm trying to figure out. If it is a bug on my side, then I want to know what the hell is startpar doing? Otherwise I think it's a bug in startpar. I must also note that this is definitely not a fluke since the same behaviour is happening on my Debian home(desktop) installation, and on my server. Both have been freshly installed from a 7.4.0 DVD image. Latest upgrades installed.

Comment: I would agree with you that it seems like a bug in startpar, and I don't have any insight as to why it would do that (especially with no mechanism in place to prevent this situation). If you don't feel like any of the existing bug reports fit this case, why not file your own? You've clearly done your research and have a legitimate issue.

Comment: Definitely NOT a bug with `startpar`. Detailed explanation [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22885365/319204). Its a pity all this is not well documented and it took more than a hour to dig through the source and understand properly.